# Pointer type conversion: effect on buffer length?

Tags: c, short, unsigned-char

`Char` is 1 byte
`unsigned short` is 2 bytes

So if I cast a `char *` to `unsigned short *`, will it change the length of the buffer?

For example I am passing `char *` and length to a VUMeter function. The function casts the `char *` to `unsigned short *`:

```
short* pln = (short*) buffer;`
```

Now I loop through the buffer, so can I use same length which was passed?

```
int peak=0;
short* pln = (short*) buffer;
for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
{
  if(abs(pln[i]) > peak)
     peak = abs(pln[i]);
}
```

For some reason I am getting application faults within the loop.

Answer (score 1):

If the size of the elements doubles, then you have room for half the elements. Casting a pointer does not resize it, is basically assumes you know what you are doing with the pointer.

So no, you can't really cast a char * to a short * and expect things to work. If you need a short * with the same values as in the char *, you need to allocate a short array and copy the elements individually from the char *.

Answer (score 0):

`unsigned short` may or may not be 2 bytes.  Let's look at the memory for your example.

```
+---+---+---+     +---+---+---+
|   |   |   | ... |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+     +---+---+---+

|<-------- len bytes -------->|
```

If `unsigned short` is 2 bytes long, you have space worth of `len/2` `unsigned short` values.  Or, more generally, you have space for `len/n` `unsigned short` values, where `n` is equal to `sizeof(unsigned short)`.

You can't cast an `unsigned char *` to `unsigned char *` and expect things to work portably.  Now, to calculate `peak`, it depends upon what you are trying to do.  If you want to find the maximum of `len` `unsigned char` values, and save that into `peak`, looping over the values will work:

```
size_t i;
unsigned short peak = 0;
for (i=0; i < len; ++i) {
    if (buffer[i] > peak) {
        peak = buffer[i];
    }
}
```

If, however, you want to "combine" `sizeof(unsigned short)` values into one `unsigned short` value, then your best bet would be to calculate the numbers by hand.

Assuming that `len` is divisible by `n`, and big-endian storage, you can do something like this (untested):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h> 

size_t factor = sizeof(unsigned short);
size_t n = len / factor;
size_t i;
unsigned short peak = 0;
if (len % factor != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Extra data at the end\n");
}   
for (i=0; i < n; ++i) {
    size_t j;
    unsigned short test = 0;
    for (j=0; j < factor; ++j) {
        test = (test << CHAR_BIT)  + buffer[i*factor+j];
    }
    if (test > peak) {
        peak = test;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The memory that's allocated will not change until you call *alloc(). The fact that the size of the data type is of different size will only influence the "step size" ("x+1" will point to x + 2 bytes), but you'll have space for half as many elements.

Personally, I'd avoid simply casting a pointer. It'll probably make the data already present in the memory block misread (two separate bytes will be now read as a single value, completely different from what you had in mind when filling the buffer with 1-byte values: two subsequent values 127, 127 will become a single value: 65535, that sort of thing). And i think it will also raise a warning in the compiler (at least GCC complains about such a cast). I think what you should do is this:

```
int x = SOMEVAL;
char * cptr = malloc(x*sizeof(char));
/* some code here - fill cptr with data */
uint16 * sptr = malloc(x*sizeof(uint16));
int i;
for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    *(sptr+i) = (uint16)(*(cptr+i));
}
free(cptr);
```

Unless my quickly made up code has some bug in it (I didn't bother to check it), it should do what you want to achieve: "cast" a pointer from char* to uint16*, but also safely copy the data without altering values (unless there's a negative value among the chars, ofc).